# GeoWebCache - WMTS Directory Structure

Tags: geowebcache, wmts

I am trying to convert an existing tile cache (created by custom process) into a usable format/structure for a GeoWebCache WMTS layer.

I can't seem to figure out the directory/naming structure required - using a layer created and seeded by GeoWebCache as a reference.  The first level is easy to understand EPSG_4326_00 - that would be spatial reference and tile matrix level.

The next level of directories, and the names of the tiles themselves is totally alien to me.

Can you explain them or point me at some documentation?

Answer (score 3):

It's not documented as it's really not intended for access by anything but GWC itself.  The closest you'll find is the source code for the `FilePathGenerator` class: https://github.com/GeoWebCache/geowebcache/blob/master/geowebcache/core/src/main/java/org/geowebcache/storage/blobstore/file/FilePathGenerator.java